Finding a CI for variance using Chi squared, when mean is known and samples are normal but not canonized
I've been meaning to find a $(1-\alpha)$ CI for the variance of a normal distribution given $n$ samples $X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n$, where the mean is known.  Where in class we've been introduced to a similar method for the mean in which the empirical mean's distribution was determined, it was then cannonized and plugged into the measure to get the CI.
my attempt 
like the class' example I started by defining an estimator, $$\hat\theta= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 -\mu^2$$
(we know the expectation so if we incorporate it into our prediction of the variance instead of taking the empirical variance).
so we assume that we take samples from normal variables distributed $X_i\sim N[\mu, \theta]$
$\hat\theta$ is distributed as a sum of n i.i.d normal R.Vs so $\hat\theta -\mu^2$ is distributed as $\chi^2_n$.
So my thinking is to construct a CI such that $$\mathbb{P}(\chi_{-\alpha/2}\le\hat\theta - \mu^2 \le \chi_{\alpha/2}) = 1-\alpha $$
$$\mathbb{P}(\chi_{-\alpha/2}+  \mu^2\le\hat\theta \le \chi_{\alpha/2}+\mu^2) = 1-\alpha $$
does this approach make sense? is it complete? do I need to somehow tweak it?

Thanks, and apologies for a lack of clarity. seeing as its my first time constructing a CI I'm uncertain.

The estimator $\hat{\theta}$ you defined is from Method-of-Moment, which is an unbiased estimator. But it does not tell you that $\hat{\theta} - \mu^2$ follows a chi-square distribution. Also when deriving CI using this technique, we are often constructing a pivotal quantity which include the parameter of interest - not an estimator (only). This technique is useful, particular in location-scale family of distributions.

I decided that it follows chi-square because chi-square is defined as the sum of iid RVs squared, should I have used the empirical variance? Or the corrected variance? I'm trying to emulate the example in class for estimating mean in which we used the empirical mean and standardized it.

Can you also please elaborate on this: "Also when deriving CI using this technique, we are often constructing a pivotal quantity which include the parameter of interest - not an estimator (only)."

Note that (A)  $\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right) -\mu^2$ is almost certainly not equal to $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\left(X_i -\mu\right)^2\right)$ even if $\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right) -\bar{x}^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\left(X_i -\bar{x}\right)^2\right)$; (B) you do not need the $\frac1n$ as $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{\left(X_i -\mu\right)^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_n$.

Note that (A) $\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right) -\mu^2$ is almost certainly not equal to $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\left(X_i -\mu\right)^2\right)$ even if $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\left(X_i -\bar{x}\right)^2\right)$.
Instead, consider that $\frac{X_i-\mu}{\sigma} \sim N(0,1)$ independently so
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{\left(X_i -\mu\right)^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_n$.
This suggests a confidence interval for $\hat \theta = \hat \sigma^2$ of $$\left[\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(X_i -\mu\right)^2}{\mathbb P(\chi^2_n \le 1-\frac{\alpha}{2})}, \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(X_i -\mu\right)^2}{\mathbb P(\chi^2_n \le \frac{\alpha}{2})}\right].$$

can you please explain the methodology? in the case where mu was unknown we picked the estimator of the empirical mean, characterized its distribution, and then found the bounds using that distribution. Here we didn't seem to pick an estimator. Essentially I'm asking what is our methodology? Solution for unknown mean - https://imgur.com/a/B2tdln9

@kal_elk122 Your image (unknown mean, known variance) in effect says $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i -\mu}{\sigma} \sim N(0,1)$ so a confidence interval for $\hat \theta = \hat \mu$ is  $\left[\frac{1}{{n}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i + \frac{ \sqrt{n}}{\sigma} \mathbb P(N(0,1) \le \frac\alpha 2 ), \frac{1}{{n}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i + \frac{ \sqrt{n}}{\sigma} \mathbb P(N(0,1) \le 1-\frac\alpha 2 ) \right]$

I tried fleshing out your solution further, I posted it in a separate answer - do you think my calculations are as intended?

also, why are we defining an estimator or an expression that involves all of our R.Vs as opposed to defining an estimator based on the distribution of a single R.V? apologies if my questions start to annoy

In each case here, the random variables are the $X_i$ while there is one unknown parameter you are producing a confidence interval for.  It gets more complicated if more parameters are unknown: for example if you did not know either of $\mu$ or $\sigma^2$ then your confidence interval for $\mu$ would involve the $t$-distribution while your confidence interval for $\sigma$ or $\sigma^2$ would involve the $\chi_{n-1}$ or $\chi^2_{n-1}$ distribution.

we need to find a $(1-\alpha)$ confidence interval for an unknown variance where the mean is known-
Let $X_1,X_2,\dots, X_k$ be iid RVs that are normally distributed $X_i\sim N[\mu, \theta]$  .
Canonizing the random variables: $$\frac{X_i-\mu}{\sqrt\theta} \sim N[0,1]$$
We note that if we sum up the squares of the k canonized R.Vs we get from definition:
$$\sum_{i=1}^k \left(\frac{X_i-\mu}{\sqrt\theta} \right)^2 \triangleq I \sim \chi^2_k$$ We note that similarly to how we've done it in a previous exercise, asserting that
$$P(I<x_l) = \frac{\alpha}{2} \implies F_I(x_l) = \frac{\alpha}{2} \implies F_I^{-1}(\frac{\alpha}{2}) = x_l$$
$$P(I>x_h) = \frac{\alpha}{2} \implies 1-F_I(x_h) = \frac{\alpha}{2} \implies F_I^{-1}(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}) = x_h$$
yields that the probability:
$$\begin{aligned}[t] P(x_l < I <x_h) &= 1-\alpha \\  P\left(F_I^{-1}(\alpha/2) \le \sum_{i=1}^k \left(\frac{X_i-\mu}{\sqrt\theta} \right)^2 \le F_I^{-1}(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}) \right) &= 1-\alpha \\ P\left(\frac{\sum (X_i-\mu)^2}{ F_I^{-1}(1-\alpha/2)} \le \theta \le \frac{\sum (X_i-\mu)^2}{ F_I^{-1}(\alpha/2)}\right) &=1-\alpha \end{aligned}$$
we found our interval where $F_I(i)$ is the CDF of a $\chi^2_k$ R.V.  (We got the last step by treating the inequality as two separate ones and them recomposing them.)
